# filter with checked checkbox and clear filter with unchecked checkbox

Tags: ecmascript-6

```js
let FlyList = [{

    "flkind": "systemi"
  }, {

    "flkind": "systemi"
  }, {

    "flkind": "systemi"
  },
  {

    "flkind": "charteri"

  }, {

    "flkind": "charteri"
  }, {

    "flkind": "charteri"
  },
];
```

```html
         <li>
          <label class="customCheck w-100" id = "filter-check2">
           <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptions" class="individual"> چارتری
           <div class="indicator"></div>
           <span class="float-left">
            2 پرواز
           </span>
          </label>
         </li>
```

I have an array. And a checkbox and I want to click it every time. Filter to be done. And whenever it was unclicked. Clean filter.

I know I should be using a loop. But I do not know how to use it.

```js
 let filter_ch = document.getElementById('filter-check2');

 filter_ch.addEventListener('change' , filt);
 function filt(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let custom_filter = FlyList.filter(kind_filt => kind_filt.flkind.indexOf("charteri")>-1);
  console.log(custom_filter);
  
 }
```

Comment: please add your HTML

Comment: You don't want to use filter, because once you remove an item from the array, it will not return. You want to use map and mark the data if it is checked or not.